# Error when trying to open localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Opening the `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` page results in a Fatal error:

```
Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in F:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php on line 8
```

I have tried commenting out the line to solve the problem but nothing happens.

```
/* Locale for messages */
       /* $locale = LanguageManager::getInstance()->getCurrentLanguage()->getMySQLLocale();
        if (! empty($locale)) {
            $this->query(
                "SET lc_messages = '" . $locale . "';",
                DatabaseInterface::CONNECT_USER,
                self::QUERY_STORE
            );
        }*/
```

but i got error

> Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first
>   statement or after any declare call in the script in
>   F:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php on line 8

please solve the issue

Comment: Well adding a comment usualy doesnt solve any problem... Show us the top 8 lines of DatabaseInterface.php

Comment: <?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * Main interface for database interactions
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin-DBI
 */
namespace PhpMyAdmin;

use PhpMyAdmin\Core;
use PhpMyAdmin\Database\DatabaseList;
use PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiExtension;
use PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiDummy;
use PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiMysql;
use PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiMysqli;
use PhpMyAdmin\Di\Container;
use PhpMyAdmin\Error;

Comment: these are the starting lines of code

Answer (score 0):

Once phpMyAdmin is installed point your browser to http://localhost/phpmyadmin to start using it. You should be able to login using any users you've setup in MySQL. If no users have been setup, use admin with no password to login. Then select Apache 2 for the webserver you wish to configure.